# How to fill elements in new page (same tab) using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to make a python program to automate filling in account information, but after clicking next, the new page where you have to put your phone number in shows up in the same tab, and i cant fill elemnts in that page because python still uses the old page's url.
how do i input text in this new page ?

Comment: Did you click next or was the click automated? Also what website was it?

Comment: I like to initially issue `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` so when I issue commands to locate elements the driver will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to appear within the browser. So after you issue the call to click(), issue a `driver.find_element_by_id(id_of_phone_input)` or use whatever appropriate method is required to find the input element. See: [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: The driver.implicitly_wait fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]